# Two dimensional Taylor Series Linear Approximation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

[image]

Hi so I'm Currently studying Multivariable Calculus and Real Analysis and have came to a wall on this question. I know from reading my notes that I have to find F(x,y), Fx(x,y), Fy(x,y), Fxx(x,y), Fyy(x,y) and, Fxy(x,y) for the first steps and then sub in the point (3,2) into each answer but I'm unsure on how to find the final expression as I don't know where some terms are coming from. Is there a step by step solution or is it different for each function?

Comment: It's a linear approximation, so you need only $F_x$ and $F_y$.

Comment: It's like approximating $\sqrt{4.1}$ using $\sqrt{4}$. You have to find a point close to $(3, 2)$ where $F$ can be computed easily.

Comment: @ArcticChar. With your first comment, you are opening a big debate ! Consider $z=(a_0+a_1x)+(b_0+b_1x)y$. $z$ is linear wrt to $x$ if $y$ is fixed and vice-versa. For me, *multilinear* is *linear*

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have pushed on further with trying to work this out and found that I actually only need F(x,y) Fx(x,y) and Fy(x,y). Then all I had to do was find the value of each by substituting in the point (3,2) and create the equation: ~ F(3,2)+Fx(3,2)*(X-3)+FY(3,2)*(y-2).